# Stop Loss time-out

Tags: pine-script

I trigger the stop loss time-out with
strategy.exit("ExitL", "Long", stop = SL)

How can I allow the price to go below the stop loss limit for a certain period of time? e.g. for 1 minute?

Only if the price stays below the stop loss limit for more than 1 minute the stop loss should come into force.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible in Pine, neither through `strategy.*()` parameters nor through managing your trade *manually* in Pine. Every time the script is executed in the realtime bar, variables are reinitialized as if the script was running for the first time on a new bar, so while you can detect events such as a stop breach, there is no way to save the time when it occurred in order to follow the duration through the next script's iterations in the realtime bar. PineCoders has a suggestion to add the possibility to time events in the realtime bar here: https://trello.com/c/ulHOgJIl